# Как сделать взаимодействие между 2 хостами на express.js

Tags: websocket, express, chat

Необходимо сделать чат с использованием вебсокетов и express.js. Все туториалы показывают, как сделать этот сайт на одном хосте, хочу понять как тоже самое можно сделать допустим на 2 разных хостах.

Answer (score 0):

Точно так же, только в настройках подключения вебсокета нужно указывать не localhost, а айпишник или dns имя другого хоста